# Recording and then Playing Audio using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPLayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation

I have an AVAudioRecorder that captures the sound. What I want is to be able to Play(AVAudioPlayer) the recorded(AVAudioRecorder) sound as it is being recorded.

I have set up the AVAudioSession property to playandRecord... but I dont know how do I program the following sort of scenario? 
Like you have your head phones on and you are walking,some one beeps at you, but u can't listen because of your headphones on, but what if your iPhone captures that beep and plays right away.

If i am recording and playing on the same file at the same time. Will that be a problem?
Any help regarding this would be anticipated.

Answer (score -2):

No there is no problem in that. recording and playing on the same file at the same time

Comment: The link mentioned in answer is expired. please update otr provide other.